# Excel: Merging Repeating Columns Within A Dataset

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, format

forgive the very basic question. I have some output from an experiment that had 3 different versions of the same question, depending on the condition. The output file treated each question as a separate column so my output looks like this, where the headers for the columns repeat:

```
Q1,Q2,Q3,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q1,Q2,Q3

1, 0, 1

-----------0, 1, 0

--------------------1, 1, 1
```

How would I be able to merge the output (preferably in Excel - my output is currently stored in an excel file, or alternatively in R), so that the desired output looks like this:

```
Q1,Q2,Q3
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

An option in `R` after reading the dataset with a function that reads thee excel file (`read_excel` etc.) would be to loop over the `unique` `names` of dataset, extract the columns, `unlist`, remove the `NA` elements (if any - assuming the blanks are `NA`)

```
nm1 <- unique(sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(df1)))
out <- sapply(nm1, function(x) na.omit(unlist(df1[grep(x, names(df1))])))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#     Q1 Q2 Q3
#[1,]  1  0  1
#[2,]  0  1  0
#[3,]  1  1  1
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` with `gather/spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(key = str_remove(key, "\\.\\d+$"), ind = rowid(key)) %>% 
   spread(key, value) %>% 
   select(-ind)
#  Q1 Q2 Q3
#1  1  0  1
#2  0  1  0
#3  1  1  1
```

---

Or another option is to `split` into a `list` of data.frames having similar columns, use `coalesce` to `reduce` it to a single vector which would remove the `NA` elements in the row and get the first non-NA element in that row

```
split.default(df1, nm1) %>%
      map_df(reduce, coalesce)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     Q1    Q2    Q3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     1
#2     0     1     0
#3     1     1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Q1 = c(1, NA, NA), Q2 = c(0, NA, NA), Q3 = c(1, 
NA, NA), Q1.1 = c(NA, 0, NA), Q2.1 = c(NA, 1, NA), Q3.1 = c(NA, 
0, NA), Q1.2 = c(NA, NA, 1), Q2.2 = c(NA, NA, 1), Q3.2 = c(NA, 
NA, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```